# ReactiveCrud, how can I delay for a moment without blocking IO before deleting data

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, rxjs, reactive-programming

So suppose I have created an api for booking hotel room by making a ticket and then I will use the information from the ticket (ex. size, bed etc.) to find available room, but if it could not find any available room I will need to delete this ticket later. So for a better user experience I don't want to suddenly delete the ticket, but I want to change the ticket status to be reject or something else and then delete it after 30second. So here what I have tried.

```
val ticket = ticketRepostiory
  .findById(request.ticketId)
  .map { it.copy(status = TicketStatus.REJECT) } // mapping new status
  .flatMap { ticketRepostiory.save(it) } // save
  .then(Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(30))) // display to user for a 30s.
  .flatMap { ticketRepostiory.deleteById(request.ticketId) } // delete it
  .block()

notificationService.notify(...etc) // notification service notify status
```

But I found the problems that this code has blocking the other code for 30s (suppose another user wants to create a new ticket it won't create or save any data to db until 30s.) So how can I delete the data after 30s without blocking other request

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it now by using .subscribe() method instead of .block()